# Android Studio TextView update after user presses Button

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, textview, android-button

I am working on CruiseShip Booking App. I have created a Menu Bar, where the user can select a cruise type. Once the user selects a cruise type. It will update the screen with relevant information. I am having trouble updating the "Visiting Places" `TextField`. I have 5 places that I need to be displayed in that `TextView`. And it needs to be displayed in a line.

Each cruise type has 5 places. So it's nameofcruiseVP1, nameofcruiseVP2, ... , nameofcruiseVP5

Here is my code:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.CheckBox
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.view.isEmpty

class CruiseType : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cruise_type)


    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.cruisetypemenu,menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

        //Get TextViews
        val crusePrice = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.cruisePrice)
        val cruiseDuration = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.cruiseDuration)
        val visitingPlace = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.visitingPlace)



        when (item.itemId){
            R.id.bahamasCruise -> {
                visitingPlace.setText(R.string.bahamasVP1)
                crusePrice.setText(R.string.bahamasCPrice)
                cruiseDuration.setText(R.string.bahamasDuration)
            }

            R.id.caribbeanCruise -> {
                visitingPlace.setText(R.string.caribbeanVP1)
                crusePrice.setText(R.string.caribbeanCPrince)
                cruiseDuration.setText(R.string.caribbeanDuration)

            }

            R.id.cubaCruise -> {
                visitingPlace.setText(R.string.cubaCVP1)
                crusePrice.setText(R.string.cubaCPrice)
                cruiseDuration.setText(R.string.cubaDuration)

            }

            R.id.samplerCruise -> {
                visitingPlace.setText(R.string.samplersVP1)
                crusePrice.setText(R.string.samplersPrice)
                cruiseDuration.setText(R.string.samplersDuration)

            }

            R.id.starCruise -> {
                visitingPlace.setText(R.string.starVP1)
                crusePrice.setText(R.string.starCPrice)
                cruiseDuration.setText(R.string.starDuration)

            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

[Here is Demo!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiiXA.gif)

[Here is the output that I am looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIeWh.png)

Comment: If you put them in an array – e.g., `<string-array name="bahamasVPs"> <item>@string/bahamasVP1</item> ...` – you could do something like `visitingPlace.text = resources.getStringArray(R.array.bahamasVPs).joinToString("\n")`.

Comment: You are setting your text with only one place's name. You can't expect the app shows all. Change your strings.

Comment: @ErenTüfekçi I know that... i cant put more than one string variable in a text view it will give an error. .setText() only takes one string variable as an argument. I can't pass it multiple. And I don't want to create 5 different textview just to display my results, that's no adaptive coding.

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you!!! This works! Such an easy fix!

Answer (score 0):

Put a string resource with 5 variables like this : `<string name="cruises">½1$s\n%2$s\n%3$s\n%4$s\n%5$s</string>`

½1$s is to be used as variable in Android String Resources

Each time you change your visiting place text, use each places strings for example :

-- I assume these are in the strings folder also

```
<string name="bahamas">Bahamas</string>
<string name="canada">Canada</string>
<string name="florida">Florida</string>
<string name="antalya">Antalya</string>
<string name="otherone">Other one</string>
```

And the code :

```
visitingPlace.setText(getString(R.string.cruises, getString(R.string.bahamas), getString(R.string.canada), getString(R.string.florida), getString(R.string.antalya), getString(R.string.florida), getString(R.string.otherone))
```

For more information :
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource

2- Alternatively, you can use strings arrays

3- You can choose to use 5 different TextViews to have more flexible UI

Comment: This is a good answer as well. I ended up going with the strings array approach. Works perfectly awesome.